# How to apply conditional ng-class?

Tags: angularjs

this is my send button which has two options 1 send activation email and second reset password. Now I waana apply reset test class to reset password list item if userstatus is notifiied or added so wanted to add conditional statement. I tried but this one is not working. Pease help.

```
<div class="active-send-select" pull-left btn-group title="{{::'title.active.filter' | translate}}">
    <button class="btn btn-large dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" ng-disabled="!actionButtonStatus.SENT">
        <i class="fa fa-envelope fa-lg"></i>
        <span class="action-button-text">{{::'label.button.send' | translate}}</span>
        <i class="icon-chevron-down pull-right" style="margin-top:-20px;"></i>
    </button>
    <ul class="dropdown-menu filter-state">
        <li class="abc"><a href="" ng-click="userstatus == 'Complete'||sendActivationNotification()"><span ng-class="{resettest: userstatus == 'Complete'}">{{::'label.dropdown.sendActivation' | translate}}</span></a></li>
       <li class="abc">
           <a href="" ng-click="userstatus == 'Notified' || onSendPasswordReset()"><span ng-class="{resettest: userstatus == 'Notified' || 'Added'}">{{::'label.dropdown.resetPassword' | translate}}</span></a>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

CSS

```
 .resettest{
      color: darkgray;
      cursor: not-allowed;
 }
```

Comment: You have 2 ng-class in your span

Comment: provide plunker for this .so we can understand your prblem othrwise you can go to this link for ngClass syntax  https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngClass

Comment: Plunker link--  https://plnkr.co/edit/9sXGscCA7xNrttamIzap?p=preview

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this with simple `class` instead of `ng-class`

```
<span class="{{userstatus == 'Notified' || 'Added'?'resettest': ' '}}">
{{::'label.dropdown.resetPassword' | translate}}
</span>
```

But i did'nt understand why you are trying to add `resettest` class two times with different condition

Comment: @icenteruser01 Edited the answer. It should work. Otherwise provide a jsFiddle

Comment: <span ng-class="{{userstatus == 'Notified' || 'Added'? 'resettest': 'anothertest' }}">{{::'label.dropdown.resetPassword' | translate}}</span>
i tried your solution but still not working

Comment: @icenteruser01 I'm using `class` only, **not `ng-class`**